# Why does this use of wxPython's EVT_KILL_FOCUS behave unexpectedly?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want my wxPython application to trigger an event when a text entry widget loses focus. I've followed the tutorial [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/27/wxpython-learning-to-focus/), which describes using `wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS`. However, **I'm getting unexpected behavior.**

The following code works fine:

```
import wx

class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Focus Tutorial 1a")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        txt = wx.TextCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "")

        txt.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.onTextKillFocus)
        """
        This next line seems to be important for working correctly,
        but I don't understand why:
        """
        txt.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.onTextFocus)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Test")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(txt, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def onTextFocus(self, event):
        print "text received focus!"

    def onTextKillFocus(self, event):
        print "text lost focus!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

When I tab back and forth from the text control to the button, or click in or out of the text control, I get the focus messages I expect.

However, when I make the following (reasonable?) edit, things go south:

```
import wx

class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Focus Tutorial 1a")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        txt = wx.TextCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "")

        txt.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.onTextKillFocus)
        """
        This next line seems to be important for working correctly,
        but I don't understand why:
        """
##        txt.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.onTextFocus)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Test")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(txt, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def onTextFocus(self, event):
        print "text received focus!"

    def onTextKillFocus(self, event):
        print "text lost focus!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The unexpected behavior is that when I try to change focus from the text box to anything else (tabbing or mouse clicks), the `'text lost focus!'` message prints once, and never again, and I can no longer edit the contents of the text control.

**Is this expected behavior? If not, what am I doing wrong?**

Python version 2.7, wxPython version 3.0.0.0, Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: I tried the modified code and on tabbing I get text lost focus repeated as long as I tab, but I am using wxPython 2.9.5.0. I can't test with 3.0 but it does sound like a bug.

Comment: Try adding an **event.Skip()** to the end of **onTextKillFocus** and **onTextFocus**.

Comment: Mike Driscoll, that worked. Thanks! If you feel like putting that as an answer, I'll accept it. I don't understand what was wrong, or why it worked, though, so if you can shed any light, I'd appreciate that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [wxEvent::Skip()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_event.html#a98eb20b76106f9a933c2eb3ee119f66c) documentation, you should almost invariably call it for non-command events as you don't want to prevent the default handling from taking place.